# What is the new path for mounted usb drives in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: usb, mount, 15.10, filemanager, location

In past versions of Ubuntu I have always been about to find a folder for external usb drives in /mnt or /media/username after they have been mounted. Since upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 I have noticed this to be missing.

Normally not an issue because I can create a new file manager instance which shows me the usb drive, however when trying to add files in a piece of software through a file browser (e.g., adding files/folders to a playlist in VLC) there is no option to choose a device other than the computer and I was unable to add files from my external drive because I cannot find a folder on my computer for it.

Is there a new location other than /media or /mnt that I need to look for this in Ubuntu 15.10? Thank you.

Comment: Nothing changes in this manner. Usb drives are mounted in `/media/$USER/` folder by default.

Comment: Check with `df` or `lsblk` where drives are mounted

Comment: Probably somewhere in `/run/user/UID/`.